# Как сделать автоподстановку в коде php?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Есть код:

```
<?php
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wp_organisations` WHERE `o_category`=121");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        echo '<span>' .$row['o_name']. '</span> 
        <span>' .$row['o_phones']. '</span> 
        <span>' .$row['o_address']. '</span><br>';
    }
    ?>
```

он используется для того, чтобы выводить списки по категориям. Однако категорий много, и не хочется писать для каждого списка отдельный файл с вышеуказанным содержимым. Как сделать так, чтобы в части "WHERE `o_category`=X" вместо Х из списка ссылок на категории подставлялось бы значение той категории, на которую переходит пользователь? А для вывода списков существовал бы единый файл-шаблон вывода? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Сделай страницу, и на ней принимай через $_GET значение текущей категории, и соответственно подставляешь его в запрос:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wp_organisations` WHERE `o_category`='".abs(intval($_GET['id']))."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
            echo '<span>' .$row['o_name']. '</span>
            <span>' .$row['o_phones']. '</span>
            <span>' .$row['o_address']. '</span><br>';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Error!';
    }
}else{
    echo 'Error!';
}
?>
```

Ссылка на категорию будет иметь следующий вид: http://example.com/category.php?id=XX

Где XX будет номер категории.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял? Делаю правку моего кода по указанному, а также делаю еще страницу со списком категорий, где для каждой проставляю ссылку http://example.com/category.php?id=XX, где вместо ХХ прописываю номера категорий, так?

Comment: @Aviko, да

Comment: ОК, спасибо, попробую, отпишусь.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало отлично!